# What is the meaning of "I've had it with [sb.]"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I read the script of the film "Terminator-2" ([here is the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html)) in English and saw a lot of unknown words and phrases.

One of them in a dialogue below:

> **WOMAN**: ...John?  John!  Get in here right now and clean up that pigsty of yours.
>
> John's friend TIM, a thirteen-year-old Hispanic kid, watches as John  replies by turning up the volume on the boom box.
>       Janelle gives up with a SLAM of the house's back door.
>
> **TIM**:  Your foster parents are kinda XXXXX, right?
>
> **JOHN**:   Gimme that Phillips right there.
>
> ..................... HOUSE - LIVING ROOM .....................
>
> Janelle storms into the room.  TOD VOIGHT, her husband, watches
>       sports on the TV.  They're both in their thirties.  Middle-class
>       working stiffs.
>
> **JANELLE**: I swear **I've had it with that goddamn kid**. He won't even answer me. (neither does he). Todd?  Are you gonna sit there or are you gonna do something?

I don't understand what "I've had it with that goddamn kid" means. "I have had" - is present perfect. But I don't understand the role of PP in this sentence. Is this some common expression?

---

P.S. I speak Russian, so it would be great if you  write some examples in Russian for better understanding

Comment: I have had *enough* with that goddamn kid.

Comment: @Raj33 No, that's not the same expression.

Comment: the meaning of this is so clear that i don't know how to explain it, self explanatory.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Zorkind Sorry, I'm Russian, and that's the problem I guess)) Because some obvious for native speakers phrases - seems weird for learners. I've wrote this sentence to [translate.google.ru](https://translate.google.ru/#en/ru/I've%20had%20it%20with%20that%20goddamn%20kid) and it gave me the translation: "У меня было это с этим проклятым ребенком" which might be interpreted as that woman had sex with the kidююющк at least has sexual implication...And obviously, this is wrong meaning...Maybe we need some Russian guy here?)

Comment: i am a Brazilian hahaha i wish i was native. i didnt mean to attack you or anything.

Comment: @Zorkind I did not take it as an attack at all)) All good.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's an expression.

Based on my search, it's slang.

> **I've had it!**
>
> expression of complete frustration when one has reached the end of his tolerance

[Source](http://www.slang-dictionary.org/I%27ve_had_it!)

Comment: It's not slang, just informal. But not even very informal. It means: "I've taken all I can take!"